# GRUB Recovery (How can I recover) the Boot repair failed ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, grubrescue, boot-repair

I am unable to recover my GRUB.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26452063/

Comment: What did you do to get into this situation ? boot-repair is suggesting a /boot partition.

Comment: You have mixed UEFI & BIOS installs. Your sda & sdc are gpt and sdb with Windows is BIOS boot with MBR(msdos) partitioning. Usually best to have just BIOS or just UEFI, with some advantages to the newer UEFI. Do not run auto fix with Boot-Repair as it will try to install BIOS grub to every drive if booted in BIOS mode. You want Windows BIOS boot loader on Windows drive. You can dual boot, but may have to turn on/off UEFI/CSM/Legacy boot mode to boot system installed in that mode. UEFI will have to be on & secure boot off to boot Ubuntu. UEFI will have to be off to boot Windows.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the detailed comment, how can I turn UEFI off? Please guide.

Comment: @Panther I got my application manager corrupted so I freed up the ubuntu space from windows and then installed ubuntu from a bootable device on that partition. Upon restarting I got grub rescue screen so I am currently using terminal via bootable ubuntu usb to repair

Comment: If you want just the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration, but for Ubuntu drives using the newer gpt partitioning, you need to add anywhere on each gpt drive a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. Then use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to just install grub2 (BIOS mode version) to gpt's protective MBR for BIOS boot. You really want to keep a Windows BIOS boot loader in the MBR of the Windows drive. Grub only boots working Windows, so when Windows breaks you want to be able to directly boot and use f8 to get into repair console. Also make repair/recovery Windows flash drive.